# Python3 - Copy File via Filepath to Windows Clipboard (Looking for Solution without PyQT)

Tags: python, windows, file, copy, clipboard

I'm looking for a function that can take a filepath as input and results in copying the actual file to the Clipboard in Windows.

I searched through StackOverflow and found a lot of solutions for copying text but only one for copying a file (via PyQT).

Is there another way to achieve this?